# Trying to remove _id in an array. It does not seem to work

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to delete the second player in the array. but everything I try doesn't work.  Any help is appreciated

Here is the stored data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdd9dfe331fa63911455c4f"),
    "name" : "goobers",
    "venue" : ObjectId("5cdc96a4f957961fed9316dd"),
    "league" : ObjectId("5cdc96b5f957961fed9316de"),
    "duespaid" : 1,
    "players" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdc96c7f957961fed9316fe"),
                    "captain" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5cdc96cbf957961fed9316ff")
            }
    ],
    "__v" : 1
}
```

Here is what I thought would work

```
db.leagues.update({
    _id:ObjectId("5cdd9dfe331fa63911455c4f")
}, { 
   $pull: { 
         "players": {
               "_id": ObjectId("5cdc96cbf957961fed9316ff")
          }
   }
})

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Here is the SCHEMA

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

//Scheme setup

var teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,

    venue: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Venue"
        },

    league: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "League"
    },

    players: [{
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Player"
        },

        captain: Number,
        name: String

        }],

    duespaid: Number

});

//var Campground = mongoose.model("League", leagueSchema); 

module.exports = mongoose.model("Team", teamSchema);
```

Comment: I just tried your given solution above with same document in the question and it is working fine. There isn't any problem with your query. Problem might be something else, so please update the question with more details about the schema and code.

Comment: Ok thank you. I posted the Schema above.  I think the issue maybe is how i have id:{ ref:"players"} .... but im not sure

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved now... the issue was in my Schema setup.. mongoose didn't like me calling the object id.  Now im able to push to the correct location and it all works.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is because mongoose automatically adds a virtual field '.id' to every object that is a simple String-Getter for the actual _id. This might be the cause of conflict.